# Trying to configure pyrebase

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

Currently, I have this python script running:

```
import pyrebase

# Config the firebase
# Create a stream
# Attatch the streamHandler
# Push the data to the firebase after analysis

config = {
  "apiKey": "Yl6***************OigD",
  "authDomain": "********.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://****.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "*****.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "/Users/ndh/Desktop/ConditioningMaintainanceAnalysis/**************.json"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()
```

This gives me following error:

```
  File "/Users/ndh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/auth/guess.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import _digest_auth_compat as auth_compat, http_proxy_digest

  File "/Users/ndh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_toolbelt/auth/_digest_auth_compat.py", line 17, in <module>
    class _HTTPDigestAuth(requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth):

AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'auth'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You are missing `auth = firebase.auth()`

Comment: Where? I tried putting `auth = firebase.auth()` after `db = firebase.database()`, but same error.

Comment: Follow this pattern [Pyrebase Authentication](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) or [client.utils.firebase.pyrebase.initialize_app](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/client.utils.firebase.pyrebase.initialize_app/). You need the `auth` reference to **sign in**.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
from Pyrebase import pyrebase
```

#just see your pyrebase lib in C:\Users\Agil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\Pyrebase

or default pyrebase library
C:\Users\Agil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\Pyrebase-master

use

```
from Pyrebase-master import pyrebase
```